# Detect when iPhone is connected to car bluetooth

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth

I'm trying to detect when I am connecting/connected to a car via bluetooth. I am currently using AVAudioSession and the properties currentRoute and outputs to determine what types of routes are connected. However, the port type 'carAudio' only correlates to when the phone connects to the car via Aux or some sort of Cable, but when connecting via bluetooth with a car's audio system the output route is always A2DP.

I understand that most cars now implement bluetoothA2DP, but I was wondering if there was some way for me to detect whether or not the bluetooth type connection is from a car, as opposed to some bluetooth headphone/speakers. (Also for both input and output, I never seen to detect BluetoothHFP)

I believe this is possible as apps like Spotify supports this functionality, and works perfectly when I connect my spotify app to the bluetooth, however my code cannot detect this connection.

Comment: did you find a solution?